# powershell list websites on remote Server 2012 R2 box

Tags: powershell

I use the following command to list websites on remote Servers 2000/2003/2008 but this command doesnt work on 2012.  Is there a similar command like this using `Get-WMIObject` that work against 2012 R2?

```
Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Server -Authentication PacketPrivacy -Impersonation Impersonate -Class IIsWebServerSetting -Namespace "root\microsoftiisv2" | 
    Select ServerComment
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by _this command doesnt work on 2012_? It would be helpful to the community to tell us what you are trying to fix. Are you sure its all 2012 servers and not just the one you were testing against.

Comment: I am not trying to fix anything, I would like to list the websites on my remote 2012 R2 Servers.  The command I listed above works for all Server OSes except 2012.  The error I get back when running this same command against a 2012 R2 Server is " Invalid namespace "root\microsoftiisv2" "  Perhaps it is a different namespace, or perhaps you dont use Get-WMIObject at all for 2012 Servers, maybe you need to use an CIM cmdlets.  I am asking the community if they know of a cmd like I have above that will work against 2012 for listing websites.  Hope this explains everything.